# Maven - Set Properties for Dependency

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

How To set properties for Dependency?

I'm in the process of converting a java project to a maven project.

Before converting to Maven, i had the jar `iijdbc.jar` and `iijdbc.properties` file in `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib`. This was all peachy.

Now that I removed everything from `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib` except `iijdbc.properties` and added the dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ingres.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>iijdbc</artifactId>
    <version>9.3-3.8.3</version>
</dependency>
```

I'm getting an error when running my project because the `iijdbc.properties` is not being picked used. I added it to my classpath, but it's still not being used.

`iijdbc.properties` only contains this line:

```
ingres.jdbc.date.empty=null
```

I did notice that if i add this line to my tomcat arguments `-Dingres.jdbc.date.empty=null`, everything works just fine too, but this is another setup piece for the next developer that comes along and i'd like to avoid this solution if possible.

Is there a way to add the line `ingres.jdbc.date.empty=null` to my iijdbc dependency so that my project works as it used to without having to have an extra file `iijdbc.properties`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to move your file to src/main/resources instead. With maven WEB-INF/lib content is auto-generated.
The convention with maven is to put resources (like properties) into src/main/resources folder.

Finally, Maven doesn't control the Tomcat environment (or only in test/debug modes), and you cannot add a property on a dependency.

Comment: Adding the property file to `src/main/resources` did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Not good approach but you can ask maven to copy the file in lib

Place the `iijdbc.properties` in iijdbc.properties and then use

```
<configuration>
  <webResources>
    <resource>
      <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
      <includes>
        <include>iijdbc.properties</include>
      <includes>        
     <targetPath>WEB-INF/lib</targetPath>
    </resource>
  </webResources>
</configuration>
```